# Multiple regression (using machine learning - how plot data)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, plotting

I wonder how I can use machine learning to plot multiple linear regression in a figure. I have one independent variable (prices of apartments) and five independent (floor, builtyear, roomnumber, square meter, kr/sqm).

The task is first to use machine learning which gives the predicted values and the actual values. Then you have to plot those values in a figure.

I have used this code:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(xx1, y, test_size=3)

Outcome: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None,
         normalize=False)

regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

Outcome:nothing

regr.predict(x_test)

Outcome: array([2.37671029, 3.91651234, 2.98472475])

np.mean((regr.predict(x_test) - y_test) ** 2)

Outcome: 2.976924398032532e-26
```

How can I plot the actual values of the dependent variable and the predicted ones in the same figure?

Comment: This does not present any kind of problem. You have two variables. Plot one on the horizontal axis and the other on the vertical axis. Perhaps you meant to ask a different question that involves more than two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There might possibly be a better way but one way of doing this is to map the variable to different aesthetics of the graph. I used python and used library `plotninne` which is as I understand tries to mimic ggplot2 from R.

`from plotnine import *
   # df is the data frame that contains all the vairables as columns
   (ggplot(df, aes('actual_value', 'predicted_value', 
   color='(dependent_var2)',

   size='dependent_var3',alpha='dependent_var4',shape='factor(dependent_var5)'))
    + geom_point()
    +theme(legend_title=element_text(size=8),
    legend_text=element_text(size=4)
    )`

This will give you following graph:
[image]